# why would we want to use both --detach switch with --interactive and --tty in docker?

Tags: docker, detach

I'm reading the [docker documentations](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#use-a-read-only-bind-mount), and I've seen this command:

```sh
$ docker run -d \
     -it \
     --name devtest \
     --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app,readonly \
     nginx:latest
```

As far as I know, using `-d` or `--detach` switch run the command outside of the current terminal emulator, and return the control of terminal back to the user. And also using `--tty -t` and `--interactive -i` is completely the opposite. Why would anyone want to use them in a command?

Comment: It's certainly uncommon, but perhaps you plan on running `docker attach` in the future to attach to an interactive program that requires a tty.

Comment: Probably, to be able to exit container shell without entire container interruption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that specific command, it doesn't make sense, since nginx does not have an interactive component. But in general, it allows you to later attach to the container with `docker attach`. E.g.

```
$ docker run --name test-no-input -d busybox /bin/sh
92c0447e0c19de090847b7a36657d3713e3795b72e413576e25ab2ce4074d64b

$ docker attach test-no-input
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first

$ docker run --name test-input -dit busybox /bin/sh
57e4adcc14878261f64d10eb7839b35d5fa65c841bbcb3cd81b6bf5b8fe9d184

$ docker attach test-input
/ # echo hello from the container
hello from the container
/ # exit
```

The first container stopped since it was running a shell, and there was no input on stdin (no `-i`). A shell exits when it finishes reading input (e.g. the end of a shell script).